# How can I create columnar output in Perl?

Tags: perl, printf

## !/usr/bin/env perl

```
 use warnings;
 use strict;

 my $text = 'hello ' x 30;

 printf "%-20s : %s\n", 'very important text', $text;
```

The output of this script looks more ore less like this:

```
very important text      : hello hello hello  hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
...
```

But I would like an output like this:

```
very important text: hello hello hello hello
                     hello hello hello hello
                     hello hello hello hello
                     ...
```

I forgot to mention: The text should have an open end in the sense that the right end of the textlines should align corresponding to the size of the terminal.

How could I change my script to reach my goal?

Comment: Are you talking about fully justified paragraphs? That is going to be both hard and ugly on a terminal. I guess you never worked with WordStar on CPM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Text::Wrap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Wrap):

```
use strict;
use Text::Wrap;

my $text = "hello " x 30;
my $init = ' ' x 20;
$Text::Wrap::columns = 80;

print wrap ( '', $init,  'very important text : ' . $text );
```

Comment: The right end of the text-lines should align corresponding to the width of the terminal. With Text::Wrap I have a fixed width of columns.

Comment: @sid_com: You can use Term::Size (http://search.cpan.org/~timpx/Term-Size-0.2/Size.pm) to get the terminal's width in columns and set $Text::Wrap::columns accordingly.

Comment: accepted this answer in liaison with the Dave Sherohman comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

 my $text = 'hello ' x 30;

 $text=~s/((\b.+?\b){8})/$1\n                       /gs;
 printf "%-20s : %s\n", 'very important text', $text;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: the text should have an open end in the sense that the right end of the text-lines should align  corresponding to the size of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure from your question precisely what format you would like your output in, I can tell you that the key to pretty output in the Perl language is to use formats.

A primer on how to use them to achieve pretty much any output formatting you would like is *[Perl format primer](http://www.webreference.com/programming/perl/format/)*.

Comment: I've had a glance at Perl6::Form but please see my comment to karthi-27

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; 
use strict;
use 5.010;
use Text::Wrap;
use Term::Size;

my $text = 'hello ' x 30;
my $init = ' ' x 22;
my( $columns, $rows ) = Term::Size::chars *STDOUT{IO};
$Text::Wrap::columns = $columns;

say wrap ( '', $init,  'very important text : ' . $text );
```